# x86 assembly get one byte from 32 bit register

Tags: c, assembly, x86, getch

I'm programmig in x86 assembly language, and I found one problem.
I call C function `getch` to get single character from stdin. But the problem is that the return value is stored in register EAX. And I want to know, how to get one character. Not 4 byte value. Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Very often you can just ignore the existence of extra bits

Comment: Note: `getch()` typically returns 1 of **256+1** different values.  Hard to fit into one `char`.

Answer (score 7):

you can use one-byte part of the `EAX` that is `AL`

```
mov [MEMORY], al
```

`AL` is the LOW byte of the `AX` register. You also can use `AH` - HIGH byte of the `AX`